# JS: How to change the image reference ending value

Tags: javascript, image

Instead of having a ton of if statements, I would like the method to display the correlated image by name, fx. clicking BlackPicture4.gif will turn it into WhitePicture4.gif. The number of the picture is passed on to the method.

I'm new to javascript, so maybe indexes[] don't work as I thought they do.

I have an array of Whitepicures:

```
imgArray[1] = new Image();
imgArray[1].src = "WhitePicture1.gif"; 
...

    function changePicture(int)
{ 

var image = document.getElementById('Img' + int); //works

image.src = imgArray[int]              //doesn't work

var thefile = "imgArray" + int + ".gif" //also doesn't work
image.src = thefile;                

}
```

I tried so many different ways, but could use help

```
html:  //as requested, but that works fine
    <img id="Img1" onclick="changePicture(1)" src="Blackpicture1.gif" width="50" height="50" >
    <img id="Img2" onclick="changePicture(2)" src="Blackpicture2.gif" width="50" height="50" >
    ...
```

Edit: The problem is solved by adding .src to "= imgArray[int]" 
Another thing I didn't think of was I had to assign the array elements INSIDE a function, rather than just on top of the file where I believe only declarations can be made.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this? I find it hard to understand what you're trying to achieve

Comment: first i need to find the image that needs to be changed, which is whatever ends with the (int) and assign it to var image.

Then i need to change image.src into the image in my array with position (int) because it corresponds to that image

Comment: "_clicking BlackPicture4.gif will turn it into_" - There is already a working `click` event handler bound to the image(s)?

Comment: I don't know how to use fiddle, especially with the pictures on my computer

Comment: clicking it is just a simple method call changePicture(1) that works

Comment: can you add your html

Comment: Start by putting curly braces (`{` and `}`) to delimit the beginning and end of you `changePicture` function. We can't make sense of your code as it is.

Comment: What is `ImageNumber` here? If you are not able to get element by Id with `document.getElementById('ImageNumber' + int);` then there might be a problem with the image elements and/or teir ids

Comment: It might help to do some introductory JavaScript tutorials, to learn how to use variables and arrays and so forth, and *then* come back to the current problem with the images. But if you're impatient: the id you use with getElementById() needs to match the id attribute in the html. You are trying to use ImageNumber1 in your Javascript, and Img1 in your html.

Comment: Change the way you call `changePicture()` to `changePicture(this)`. Then `int` (should be renamed, e.g. `img`) is a reference to the clicked picture and not only  a number. Then you can use `img.src = img.src.replace("White", "Black")` in `changePicture`

Comment: @J.Doe you could also use Plunker at plnkr.co. In that you can add full fledged code and share it. As for the images, you can use imgur.com to upload the image, and then use the link in your html.

Comment: Its image.src = imgArray[int].src. Probably you checked code before i'd modified my answer :) Check my answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ***may*** work im not sure

```
imgArray[1] = new Image();
imgArray[1].src = "WhitePicture1.gif";
var x;
function changePicture(x) {
var image = document.getElementById('Img' + x);
image.src = imgArray[x].src;
}
```

Comment: It's tough choice when 2 answers were right, but since you kept it in my format and took the time to do it in both jquery and javascript :)

Answer (score 1):

In this example, the pic with `id='1'` will be converted into a pic with `id='2'`:

```js
$("img").click(function() {
  var x = $(this).attr("id");
  x++;
  var y = $("#" + x).attr("src");
  $(this).html("");
  $(this).html("<img src='" + y "'>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="pic1.jpg" id="1">
<img src="pictobereplaced.jpg" id="2">
```

Comment: Where did you find a `jQuery` tag or reference in the question?

Comment: Note that if you have more than 1 pic you can switch to it by keeping an id with a different id for it

Comment: Jquery is a javascript library

Comment: You can do it using jquery which is easier but sorry if you wanted javascript only

Comment: As the description of the "JavaScript" tag says, "Unless another tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected." Having said that, the code you've shown won't work because you're trying to set the inner html of the clicked img to be another img, and img elements can't contain other elements.

Comment: BTW, if you point your example at real image urls, (say something from wikicommons), your example would "work" and be more compelling.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to do might be

```
function changePicture(int){
    document.getElementById('Img'+int+'').setAttribute('src',imageArray[int].src);
}
```

Comment: Okay it knows what picture to change now, but when trying to add new picture i get error :
"GET file:///C:/.../undefined Not Found"

..But imgArray[int] should not be undefined?

Comment: sure you still have that image at that path?

Comment: as i said it would be  image.src = imgArray[1].src.

Comment: Oh i was missing the .src at the end! thats it! thanks